# Remove selection gray shadow from html input on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, xcode, uiwebview

I'm currently working on html rich text editor for my iOS application,so,the setup is simple,i have a UIWebView loading my editor code,the html input is a **'contentEditable' DIV**.

The problem is that every time i select this div to enter some text,a light gray frame appears on the input frame,telling the user that the textfield has been selected.

**NOTE**:You can see the effect in this quick [video](http://litsdevelopment.com/temporary/teste.mov)

My question is:**How to remove this light gray frame?**

My html file is bellow:

```
<html>

<head>

    <style type="text/css">

        :focus{

            outline:0px solid transparent;

        }

        DIV::-moz-focus-inner {
            background-color:#ff0000;
            border: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        ul{
            margin-left:-10px;
        }
        ol{
            margin-left:-10px;
        }

        blockquote {

            border-left:#ff0000 5px double;
            margin-left:0px;

        }

    </style>

</head>

<body onload="addImgAttributes();checkBlockquote();" topmargin="0" bottommargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0">

    <div
        id="content"
        class="content"
        contenteditable="true"
        style="font-family: Helvetica; background-color:#fff; color:#000; height:258px;"
        autocapitalize="off"
        autocorrect="off"
        autocomplete="off"
        spellCheck="false"
    >
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ EDIT 1 -----

After the comment of @StephenJ i realized that this gray frame might be a subview of the UIWebView and not a css property.I logged the view hierarchy from the UIWebView in the exact moment that the frame appeared,this is the log:

```
2013-04-17 21:37:00.919 StrangeThings[1182:c07] <UIWebView: 0xa5ec3f0; frame = (7 7; 306 258); layer = <CALayer: 0xa5edf30>>
2013-04-17 21:37:00.919 StrangeThings[1182:c07] <_UIWebViewScrollView: 0xa5f7850; frame = (0 0; 306 258); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xa5f7e20>; layer = <CALayer: 0xa5f7aa0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
2013-04-17 21:37:00.920 StrangeThings[1182:c07] <UIImageView: 0xa5f90c0; frame = (0 0; 54 54); transform = [-1, 0, -0, -1, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa5f9120>>
2013-04-17 21:37:00.920 StrangeThings[1182:c07] <UIImageView: 0xa5f9030; frame = (0 0; 54 54); transform = [0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa5f9090>>
2013-04-17 21:37:00.920 StrangeThings[1182:c07] <UIImageView: 0xa5f8fa0; frame = (0 0; 54 54); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa5f9000>>
2013-04-17 21:37:00.921 StrangeThings[1182:c07] <UIImageView: 0xa5f8b90; frame = (0 0; 54 54); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa5f8f70>>
2013-04-17 21:37:00.921 StrangeThings[1182:c07] <UIImageView: 0xa5f8b00; frame = (-14.5 14.5; 30 1); transform = [0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa5f8b60>>
2013-04-17 21:37:00.922 StrangeThings[1182:c07] <UIImageView: 0xa5f8a70; frame = (-14.5 14.5; 30 1); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa5f8ad0>>
2013-04-17 21:37:00.922 StrangeThings[1182:c07] <UIImageView: 0xa5f89e0; frame = (0 0; 1 30); transform = [-1, 0, -0, -1, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa5f8a40>>
2013-04-17 21:37:00.922 StrangeThings[1182:c07] <UIImageView: 0xa5f8950; frame = (0 0; 1 30); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa5f89b0>>
2013-04-17 21:37:00.923 StrangeThings[1182:c07] <UIImageView: 0xa5f88c0; frame = (0 228; 306 30); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa5f8920>>
2013-04-17 21:37:00.923 StrangeThings[1182:c07] <UIImageView: 0xa5f8750; frame = (0 0; 306 30); transform = [-1, 0, -0, -1, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa5f8630>>
2013-04-17 21:37:00.924 StrangeThings[1182:c07] <UIWebBrowserView: 0xc270400; frame = (0 0; 306 258); text = ''; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xa5f5ac0>; layer = <UIWebLayer: 0xa5f0820>>
2013-04-17 21:37:00.925 StrangeThings[1182:c07] <UIHighlightView: 0xa5ef210; frame = (-4 -4; 314 266); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa5c0730>>
2013-04-17 21:37:00.925 StrangeThings[1182:c07] <UIImageView: 0xa0bebc0; frame = (0 251; 306 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa0bec60>>
2013-04-17 21:37:00.925 StrangeThings[1182:c07] <UIImageView: 0xa0b37d0; frame = (299 0; 7 258); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa0becd0>>
```

After analyzing all these subviews i found one named `UIHighlightView`,as the name confirm,this view might highlighting the webView.So my second question is:**How to remove this view?**

Comment: Did you try `-webkit-appearance:none`?

Comment: Try adding `outline: none;` to the input `:focus` pseudo element.

Comment: @Bluey i already tried this but it didn't worked!

Comment: @pbibergal i tried this wright now it doesn't work!

Comment: First, I would observe the subviews on the webView to figure out if a native subview is added or if it's on the webpage renderer. This is the "I have no idea" approach, but it narrows down where to fix.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen,i'll give it a shot!

Comment: @StephenJ i logged the WebView view hierarchy and i found a view name 'UIHighlightView',i'll try to remove this view now!

Comment: @StephenJ i can't figure out how to remove this UIHighlightedView,can you help me?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's as simple as setting the following CSS rule.

```
div {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

This makes the applied shadow transparent so it seems like it's gone.

Edit: Here's a [demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/BJh6R/1/).

Comment: Thanks @Sacha for your answer,it perfectly worked,simple and clean!

Comment: I must wait 11 hours to give you the bounty!

Comment: This issue has resurfaced on iOS13. This solution is not working :(