# UIWebView keyboard when setting body contenteditable to true

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have two different views handled by my view controller, a simple uitextfield along with a uiwebview.  When the view is shown the text field becomes the first responder and obviously the keyboard is shown.  I've set the html displayed in the webview to contain the attribute contenteditable for the body tag but as a result I now notice when the user taps the webview, the keyboard flickers.  The flicker is because the webview animates in it's keyboard with the custom toolbar.  I'm simply hiding the toolbar for now but the flicker looks pretty bad.  I've found if I set contenteditable on a specific div, the flicker problem goes away but I really do want all elements to remain contenteditable.  Anybody else experience anything similar?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051197/remove-selection-gray-shadow-from-html-input-on-ios